# OpenCV Gaussian Mixture Model of histogram

Tags: opencv

Given a histogram I want to train a Gaussian Mixture Model:

```
int calcGMMThreshold(cv::Mat & hist, cv::Mat & labels){

   cv::Mat samples(hist.rows,2, CV_32FC1); // for building 2 dim samples

    // output variables
    cv::Mat probs, log_likelihoods;

   // building 2 dimensional Mat -->[value][#value]
   for(int i = 0; i<hist.rows; i++)
   {
       samples.at<float>(i,0) = (float)i;
       samples.at<float>(i,1) = hist.at<float>(i);
   }

   assert(samples.cols == 2);
   assert(samples.rows == 256);

   ///set up gmm

   //gmm object with 3 gmms
   cv::EM gmm(3);


   /*train gmms*/
   gmm.train(samples, log_likelihoods, labels, probs);

}
```

When I [plot](http://s22.postimg.org/6ldau71r5/histogram.jpg) the histogram with the labels for me it looks like that my gmms separate the absolute values and not the 2 dimensional input.

I would have expected 3 Gaussians with their means at each peak of the histogram.

Comment: are you sure you want to train a 2D gmm? isn't your data 1D?

Comment: I want to get the chunks of intensities. I think that the result that I plotted is that of a 1d gmm? So that's not what I want.

Comment: it is true, that plotting a histogram requires it's labels i.e. the buckets of the histogram. But the gmm in your example "sees" a set of 2D data (label + value) and approximates 2D gaussian distributions on them, no? You should do gmm on values only.

Comment: actually you're trying to do a gmm of the labels of the bucket and weighing them by the values of your histogram if I understand correctly, in that case your samples are the values 0 through hist.rows and your weights are the values of hist

Comment: You can test it like this (I don't see a weighted gmm in opencv): 1. define a sample rate `S` (say 1000). 2. generate `hist.at<float>(b)/S` samples (copies of `b`) for every `b=0..hist.rows-1` and a map from sample index to `b`. 3. perform 1D gmm and map the resulting labels to `b`.

Comment: OR simply compute the gmm on your input data (the input for the histogram) ;)

Comment: I get it. Was a little bit confused there! Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute a gaussian mixture model use the actual image data not the histogram as intended in the code above.